# IPTABLES match string let 5 seconds and drop

Tags: iptables

I'm looking for a strange rule !

I wish to match a string with iptables, maintain the connexion in order to start the download, but after 2 seconds downloading, I wish to drop the connexion.
PS: I know that this concept will corrupt files, it is what i want !

All suggestions are welcome !
Thanks

Comment: Can you make your question clearly !!!

Comment: An iptables -L -v -n output in your question helped you a lot to get meaningful answers.

Comment: So you want to allow the connection to start, but then stop.  Have you thought about pulling out the ethernet cable part way through?

Comment: I will try to explain with more details.

I need to stop during downloads some files that content special headers. These headers are matched with strings from iptables.
My idea was to play with recent and seconds in order to start downloads.
If the header is matched, in this case, I let few seconds and drop.

I tried to play with fail2ban rules, but results are not what i am looking for.
Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about "few bytes and drop" instead "few seconds and drop"?

if ok, URL below may help your idea.

[How to identify download traffic using iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/249520/how-to-identify-download-traffic-using-iptables)

Comment: Yes, it is useful, how to add a string matching condition in these chains ?